# Using Facebook's API to post a video using the feed dialog fails

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to post a video to a user's timeline using Facebook's feed dialog. When I use the javascript SDK with:

```
FB.ui({
     method:'feed',
     name: 'testing',
     link: 'http://www.facebook.com',
     picture: 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/1CE6W5BubQo/0.jpg',
     source: 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1CE6W5BubQo'
});
```

I get:

[image: As you can see, no thumbnail and no video player]

And this is missing the thumbnail and video player. I tried adding `type: 'video'` to the parameters and I also tried replacing the `source` parameter with a direct link to the .swf file, but that didn't help. I'm not sure if this is a bug or if I'm doing something wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do like that:

```
FB.ui(
  {
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'testing',
    link: 'http://www.facebook.com',
    picture: 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/1CE6W5BubQo/0.jpg',
    //caption: '',
    description: '',
    source: 'https://www.youtube.com/v/1CE6W5BubQo?version=3&autohide=1&autoplay=1'
  },...
```

[image]

Comment: That does post the video to the timeline, but it's unplayable. Clicking on the arrow does nothing. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I have no problem to play this video, https://www.facebook.com/limkokhole/posts/10202840623755631. Can you posts a public video for me to check?

Comment: OK, this is super strange. I can play it when I look at the individual post or when I look at my timeline from another profile, but I can't play it when I look at my own timeline. Go Facebook API! But thanks to you for the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this.

change your source

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1CE6W5BubQo

into this

https://youtube.googleapis.com/v/1CE6W5BubQo

and

url or link to https://youtube.googleapis.com/v/1CE6W5BubQo

Answer (score 0):

This is by design as per facebook --

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/589975484398226?browse=external_tasks_search_results_526fc388b99e18881434478

I am still trying to figure out a way out of this .