# Add Facebook Share Button with Video to Website

Tags: facebook, web, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-share

I am adding a Facebook Share button to my website.  I am able to set it up to include a picture in the post, but I'd like it to include a video.  **How would I do this using the [FB.ui feed parameters](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.3)?**

Here is my working code for adding a picture:

```
<!-- Facebook share script -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3&appId=*********";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

 <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="#{@project_url}" data-layout="icon">
       <%= image_tag "facebook.png", :class=>"social_icon" %>
 </div>

$('.fb-share-button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    FB.ui(
        {
        method: 'feed',
        name: "<%=@project.user.username%>",
        link: '<%=@project_url%>',
        picture: '<%=@project.images.first.image_file_url%>',
        caption: ' ',
        description: ' ',
        message: ''
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the FB feed method, I used share, and this drew from the metatags I included for my webpage.  This ended up working!

For reference, this is what it looked like:

```
$('.fb-share-button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    FB.ui({
      method: 'share',
      href: '<%=@project_url%>',
    }, function(response){});
    });
```

and my metatags:

```
<!-- Facebook tags -->
<meta property="fb:app_id"             content="811332718952118"/>
<meta property="og:type"               content="video.other"/>
<meta property="og:url"                content="<%=@project_url%>" />
<meta property="og:title"              content="<%=@project.user.username%>'s Spin" />
<meta property="og:description"        content=" " />
<meta property="og:video"              content="<%=@project.video.video_file_url%>" />
<meta property="og:video:type"         content="video/mp4" />
<meta property="og:video:width"        content="700"/>
<meta property="og:video:height"       content="700"/>
<meta property="og:image"              content="<%=@project.spins.first.images.order(:position).first.image_file_url%>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the url to the video in the `source` parameter. You can read more [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.3#params).

> source: The URL of a media file (either SWF or MP3) attached to this
>   post. If SWF, you must also specify picture to provide a thumbnail for
>   the video.

Comment: thanks for your help - even after adding the source, the video does not appear in the shared post

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798314/using-facebooks-api-to-post-a-video-using-the-feed-dialog-fails

Comment: I could be wrong but I think the url for the video must be a secure url i.e. https://